# Logging exceptions in WCF with IErrorHandler inside HandleError or ProvideFault?

Tags: wcf, exception, error-handling, service

I'm using IErrorHandler to do exception handling in WCF and now I want to log the exceptions, along with the stack trace and the user that caused the exception.

The only way I can see to get the user that caused the exception is:

OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.Security.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity

...But this only seems to work inside ProvideFault, and not inside HandleError.  Is there a way to get the user inside HandleError?  I would like to use HandleError instead of ProvideFault as that's called on a background thread and meant for error logging, right?

Answer (score 3):

The two methods of the IErrorHandler have quite well defined responsibilities:

- *HandleError* is here to handle all uncaught exceptions - that's why it's the best place to do your logging - that's really its whole reason to be
- *ProvideFault* is tasked with turning your .NET exception into an interoperable SOAP fault - or ignore the exception alltogether

Of course, there's nothing technically stopping you from doing your logging in the `ProvideFault` method - it's just not the place I would go look for that functionality if I ever had to look for it. I tend to like to follow to principle of least surprise - if the method is called `ProvideFault`, I only expect it to provide a `FaultException<T>` - not do a lot of other things, too.

To get access to your service's security context, use this snippet of code:

```
ServiceSecurityContext secCtx = ServiceSecurityContext.Current;

if(secCtx.PrimaryIdentity != null)
{
   // do something with primary identity
}
```

Comment: I do agree, but how does one get the user info (ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity) from inside the HandleError method?

Comment: In my environment accessing ServiceSecurityContext.Current in HandleError() throws ObjectDisposedException with "Message is closed" text.

Comment: @marc_s, have you actually tried it? While it seems that the ProvideFault() method runs at a time that there is an operation (and security) context, the HandleError() method runs after the contexts have been torn down.

Comment: Hi @marc_s, can you check my problem,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508724/intercept-providefault-method-in-wcf