# Log4Net & WCF IErrorHandler - ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name returns NullReferenceException

Tags: wcf, log4net, handleerror, ierrorhandler

I am using a WCF Service and I have implemented *IErrorHandler*.  In the *HandleError* method, I want to retrieve the caller's username in order to set a *ThreadContext* property for *Log4Net* (to save the username along with the exception details in SQL Server)

My code is working well if I avoid trying to retrieve the caller's username.

This is the line of code inside the HandleError method which is returning a ***NullReferenceException***:

```
string username = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name;
```

It seems that at the point the *HandleError* method of *IErrorHandler* kicks in, the original caller information has been disposed.

Does anyone have any idea how I can retrieve the caller's username inside the *HandlerError* method of *IErrorHandler*?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wasn't able to understand if you can get the name outside of the HandleError method or if it also fails. Also, are you sure that the system invoking the service has an associated windows account?

Comment: Hi Sergio, thanks for your response.  I just saw this message now and I won't be back at work until Monday.  I'm pretty sure I was able to retrieve the username inside the ProvideFault method, just not the HandleError method.  I'll have to get back to you Monday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to those who responded to help.  My security appears to be configured correctly but I cannot retrieve the username in the *HandleError* method of the *IErrorHandler* interface in the WCF service.  However, I am able to retrieve the username in the *ProvideFault* method.  So, I declared a class level variable in the *ErrorHandler* (*IErrorHandler*) class which is set during the *ProvideFault* method and then read and logged with the exception in the ErrorHandler method.  This is a "workaround" and not my preference, but unfortunately I cannot seem to access the security context inside the *HandleError* method.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior
{
    private string username = null;

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        //Log the exception along with the username.
        //...logging call including the username class member string...

        //Return true to indicate we have performed our behaviour.
        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
            //Retrieve the username.
            username = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this exception then you probably do not have security configured correctly. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2869481/106567

Answer (score 0):

Using a Class Level variable seems to have a side effect. The same instance of the handler seems to be used for every error handled (to be confirmed). So if 2 errors are raised at the exact same time, I don't know how it will react. So instead, in ProvideFault, I used the exception received as argument to transport the username to the HandleError method. An exception has a «Data» property which is a dictionary. I just add two key-value pairs (one for PrimaryIdentity and one for WindowsIdentity). In HandleError, I retrieved the information in the Data property of the exception received as argument.