# HandleError vs. ProvideFault inconsistencies in workflow service, how to handle?

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4

In our WF4 workflow service, we try to be as robust as possible. One of the things we do is to log errors inside HandleError and ProvideFault ([IErrorhandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). The documentation states clearly that HandleError would be the right place to do the logging, but I see some strange things happen:

1. I see some errors that only trigger **ProvideFault**, but never HandleError, one example was:

   *System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.ServiceModel.Activities.Dispatcher.DurableInstanceManager.GetInstanceAsyncResult.GetInstance()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activities.Dispatcher.DurableInstanceManager.GetInstanceAsyncResult..ctor*
2. There are also some errors that only trigger **HandleError**, but never ProvideFault, one example was:

   *System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d).
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)*
3. Finally there are errors that trigger **both**, first ProvideFault and then HandleError (on a background thread)
4. If possible, I want to log the corresponding incoming message, too. I do this with *OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()* This usually only works in ProvideFault, in HandleError we don't have the RequestContext any more

So my conclusion was, to log ALL errors, I must log in both methods. But that leads to a lot of duplicated log entries, due to 3..

My current workaround was to "remember" the last logged exception from ProvideFault, and ignore it if the same exception enters HandleError. Looks not very clean to me.

Has anybody a better, reliable method to log **all** errors that can happen inside a WF service?

And please don't point to [Logging exceptions in WCF with IErrorHandler inside HandleError or ProvideFault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869436/logging-exceptions-in-wcf-with-ierrorhandler-inside-handleerror-or-providefault) as that does not provide any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen scenario 2 happen in a different context (BizTalk adapter), and it seems that `HandleError` is called because there's an exception that occurs in the adapter, but `ProvideFault` is **not** called because there's no message to actually return - the fault occurred in such a way that it prevent the adapter from actually generating/reading/translating the message and passing it on to the pipeline.  This seems to preclude even a **fault** message from getting generated.  Having a failure to read from a pipe would seem to constitute this - your service doesn't know if it failed because it never even connected or if it failed because the remote server failed.  Things like `TransactionAbortedException` could also cause this, or (in my particular case), a `SqlException` can cause it.

This should give some clue for case #1, which I haven't seen myself or reproduced: it's due to improper exception handling somewhere in the messaging chain.  In this case, a fault message was generated but something higher up the chain failed to handle the exception in such a way that `HandleError` could be called.  A `NullReferenceException` makes sense here - if you don't handle null checks properly it's hard to say what else will happen down the line in this kind of case.

As far as resolving this goes, I would probably try to log in both places, with some additional information explaining where the log came from.  That'd be failsafe, even if it does duplicate logging.  On the other hand, if you have a list of exceptions that generate one or both of these scenarios, you might implement logic to check for what kind of exception it is (or where it occurred) - perhaps doing less logging if it's an exception that's likely to be handled by the other method.